# Influxdb Write with REST API and Json data

Tags: json, influxdb

Influx, how do I upload a JSON with Rest Api?

When i read data from Influx using say Rest+query, it comes in JSON format. Now to upload they are saying json is deprecated and we have to do it in binary format, really?

Read using this gives me data in JSON format
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode “db=my_db" --data-urlencode "q=select * from \”server1.rte.set\" limit 1">test.txt

Write has to be this binary format
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=my_db' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'

Why would anybody do this? Keep both json or keep both binary.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of InfluxDB doesn't support the JSON write path or a binary protocol. The predominant reason it was deprecated was that decoding JSON was the largest performance bottleneck in the system.

For a more information see the github issue comments [107043910](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/2696#issuecomment-107043910) and [106968181](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/2696#issuecomment-106968181).